# Creating 1M NaCl solution using PACKMOL

Tags: molecular-modeling, atomistic-simulation, packmol

I want to create a **1M NaCl solution** in a **1nm X 1nm X 1nm** size cell using PACKMOL. So, what should be the NaCl:H2O ratio for this concentration? My calculation is -

1M NaCl = 1 mole NaCl + 1000 mL H2O
= 1 mole NaCl + 1000 g H2O
= 1 mole NaCl + 55.85 mole H2O

So, NaCl:H2O = 1:55.85.

What is the role of simulation cell size in this case? How does it affect the molar concentration?